# Continuity of a map into space of Radon measures on $[0,1]^{2}$

Tags: measure-theory, weak-convergence

In [this paper](http://www.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/~spurny/doc/papers/martingaly09.pdf), with $H_{1}$ the 1-dimensional normalized Haudsdorff measure on the plane, a measure $\zeta_{\alpha}$ on $[0,1]^{2}$ is defined for $\alpha \in [0,1]$ by

$$ 
  \zeta_{\alpha} :=
  \begin{cases}
    \delta_{(0,0)}, &\text{if } \alpha = 0, \\
    \frac{1}{H_{1}(A(\alpha))}H_{1}\vert_{A(\alpha)} &\text{if } \alpha \in (0,1) \\
    \delta_{(1,1)} & \text{if } \alpha = 1,
  \end{cases}
$$
where $A(\alpha) := \{(u,v) \in [0,1]^{2} : u+v = 2\alpha\}$ and $\delta_x$ denotes the Dirac measure concentrated on $x$. It is then claimed that $\alpha \mapsto \zeta_{\alpha}$ is continuous from $[0,1]$ to the space of Radon measures on $[0,1]^{2}$ equipped with the weak topology. However, it seems to me that if we take $\alpha_{n}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{n}$, $n\geq 3$, so that $\alpha_{n} \to \alpha$, then $\zeta_{a_{n}}(A(1/2)) =0$ but $\zeta_{1/2}(A(1/2)) = 1$. By the [portmanteau theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures), $\zeta_{\alpha_{n}} \not\to \zeta_{1/2}$. (I'm only pretty sure that $A(1/2)$ is a continuity set, so this might be where I'm erring.) **Where's the error here?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A(1/2)$ is closed with empty interior and thus 
$$ \zeta_{1/2} (\partial A(1/2)) = \zeta_{1/2} (A(1/2)) = 1 $$
by the definition of $\zeta_\alpha$; so $A(1/2)$ is not a continuity set for $\zeta_{1/2}$.

Comment: Oh yes, I was not considering $A$ as a subset of the 2-dimensional square. Thank you. Any idea of an easy way to show the claimed continuity?

Comment: @QuinnCulver: If $f\in C([0,1]^2)$ then $f$ is uniformly continuous. For continuity on $(0,1)$: Since $\int f d\zeta_{\alpha}$ is just the line integral of $f$ along the curve $A_\alpha$, you should be able to change variables to make the integration domain $[0,1]$ for each $\alpha$ and show the integrand converges uniformly => the integral converges. You'll need a separate argument for the endpoints, but the uniform continuity will again suffice.